# Hibernate - Неправильный запрос к БД

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, запрос

**Привет всем!** 
Такая ситуация:

Есть связь ManyToMany(в базе это 2 таблицы сущности и одна связующая).

**При обновлении записи Product, удаляеться запись со сводной/связующей таблицы. (А не должна!)** 
**Hibernate формирует запрос на удаление... Почему?** 
При обновлении Order, все норм - "сводная" запись не пропадает..

Вот код и запросы Hibernate. 
Огромное спасибо наперед, может кто тыкнет носом?)))

**Код контроллера и двух сущностей:**
   package com.blackside.group.entity;

```
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "`ORDER`")
    public class Order {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "`ID`", nullable = false)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "`START_ADRESS`")
        private String startAdress;

        @Column(name = "`END_ADRESS`")
        private String endAdress;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders")
        private Set<Product> products;
        public Order() {
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getStartAdress() {
            return this.startAdress;
        }

        public String getEndAdress() {
            return this.endAdress;
        }

        public Set<Product> getProducts() {
            return this.products;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setStartAdress(String startAdress) {
            this.startAdress = startAdress;
        }

        public void setEndAdress(String endAdress) {
            this.endAdress = endAdress;
        }

        public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
            this.products = products;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Order{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", startAdress='" + startAdress + '\'' +
                    ", endAdress='" + endAdress + '\'' +
                    ", products=" + products +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    package com.blackside.group.entity;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "`PRODUCT`")
    public class Product {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "`ID`", nullable = false)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "`NAME`")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "`DESCRIPTION`")
        private String description;

        @Column(name = "`PRICE`")
        private int price;

        @ManyToMany(
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY
        )
        @JoinTable(name = "`PRODUCT_ORDER`",
                joinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "`PRODUCT_ID`")
                },
                inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "`ORDER_ID`")
                }
        )
        private Set<Order> orders ;

        public Product() {
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return this.description;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
            return this.price;
        }

        public Set<Order> getOrders() {
            return this.orders;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
            this.orders = orders;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Product{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                    ", price=" + price +
                    ", orders=" + orders +
                    '}';
        }
    }

package com.blackside.group.controller;

import com.blackside.group.entity.Order;
import com.blackside.group.entity.Product;
import com.blackside.group.service.OrderService;
import com.blackside.group.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("productService")
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getListProduct(ModelMap model) {
        List<Product> productList = productService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("productList", productList);
        return "product";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addProduct(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("action", "Add new");

        Product product = new Product();
        model.addAttribute("product", product);

        return "productCreate";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/product/new" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveProduct(Product product) {

        productService.add(product);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/product/delete/{idProduct}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable int idProduct) {
        productService.delete(idProduct);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {  "/product/edit/{idProduct}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editProduct(@PathVariable int idProduct, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("action", "Edit");

        Product product = productService.get(idProduct);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        return "productForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {  "/product/edit/{idProduct}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateProduct(Product product) {
        productService.update(product);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }
}
```

**Запросы:**

при редактировании  Product:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        product0_.`ID` as ID1_2_1_,
        product0_.`DESCRIPTION` as DESCRIPT2_2_1_,
        product0_.`NAME` as NAME3_2_1_,
        product0_.`PRICE` as PRICE4_2_1_,
        orders1_.`PRODUCT_ID` as PRODUCT_1_2_3_,
        order2_.`ID` as ORDER_ID2_1_3_,
        order2_.`ID` as ID1_0_0_,
        order2_.`END_ADRESS` as END_ADRE2_0_0_,
        order2_.`START_ADRESS` as START_AD3_0_0_ 
    from
        `PRODUCT` product0_ 
    left outer join
        `PRODUCT_ORDER` orders1_ 
            on product0_.`ID`=orders1_.`PRODUCT_ID` 
    left outer join
        `
    ORDER` order2_ 
        on orders1_.`ORDER_ID`=order2_.`ID` where
            product0_.`ID`=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        `PRODUCT_ORDER` 
    where
        `PRODUCT_ID`=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.`ID` as ID1_2_0_,
        this_.`DESCRIPTION` as DESCRIPT2_2_0_,
        this_.`NAME` as NAME3_2_0_,
        this_.`PRICE` as PRICE4_2_0_ 
    from
        `PRODUCT` this_
```

при редактировании  Order:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        order0_.`ID` as ID1_0_1_,
        order0_.`END_ADRESS` as END_ADRE2_0_1_,
        order0_.`START_ADRESS` as START_AD3_0_1_,
        products1_.`ORDER_ID` as ORDER_ID2_0_3_,
        product2_.`ID` as PRODUCT_1_1_3_,
        product2_.`ID` as ID1_2_0_,
        product2_.`DESCRIPTION` as DESCRIPT2_2_0_,
        product2_.`NAME` as NAME3_2_0_,
        product2_.`PRICE` as PRICE4_2_0_ 
    from
        `
    ORDER` order0_ left outer join
        `PRODUCT_ORDER` products1_ 
            on order0_.`ID`=products1_.`ORDER_ID` 
    left outer join
        `PRODUCT` product2_ 
            on products1_.`PRODUCT_ID`=product2_.`ID` 
    where
        order0_.`ID`=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.`ID` as ID1_0_0_,
        this_.`END_ADRESS` as END_ADRE2_0_0_,
        this_.`START_ADRESS` as START_AD3_0_0_ 
    from
        `
    ORDER` this_
```

[image: Вот что говорит debug при при обновлении формы редактирования:]
[image: **Вот что говорит debug при при выводе формы редактирования:**]

Comment: Что находится в сущностях перед обновлением? Связи не теряются?

Comment: Я имел ввиду в экземплярах java-классов что находится.

Comment: А как это проверить?

Comment: в debug-режиме на методе обновления

Comment: Добавил скрин при обновлении...

Comment: Вот что говорит debug при при обновлении формы

Comment: В выводе нет HIBERNATE сообщения про SQL update - это почему?

Comment: А вот это и есть вопрос - почкму Хибер бросает не тот запрос?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу так:
Дернул обьект из сессии и забил через сеттеры....

public void update(Order item) {
//          getCurSes().merge(item);

```
Order entity = (Order) getCurSes().get(Order.class, item.getId());
if(entity!=null){
  entity.setStartAdress(item.getStartAdress());
  entity.setEndAdress(item.getEndAdress());
}
```

}